# Encrypting Phone Calls?

Tags: calls, hardware, encryption

When we perform the system encryption on a device, can the calls be encrypted too?

Comment: If you are asking by encrypting your device are phone calls made from the device are encrypted *NO* , they aren't . There are special phones that can encrypt calls and cost a bomb

Comment: @beeshyams there are also special apps that allow for encrypted calls and do *not* cost a bomb (Redphone, Signal etc.). But as usual: If you encrypt a call on one end, the other end gets gibberish unless it can decrypt it. So both sides must support that – which normally means both ends using the same app.

Comment: @izzy: True didn't think of that

Comment: @beeshyams OK, so let's agree on "the one (system encryption) is completely independent of the other (call encryption)" – and thus the question should read "(How) can I do encrypted calls"?